# Change I change Xcode status line to something other than "custom build script"?

Tags: xcode, xcode6, xcode6.4

A few of our build scripts take a while. It would be nice if we could update the Xcode build status line from within the script to something other than "Running X of Y custom shell scripts":

[image]

Can this be done?